# Problem with sequences and equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

For every natural number $n \ge 2$, let us consider the equation:
$$1 \times 2^x+2 \times3^x + \dots + (n-1) \times n^x=(n+1)^x,$$
which has the unique solution $x_n$. Compute:
$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac {x_n}{n \ln n}.$$

My try: I proved that $x_n \ge \frac {\ln (n-1)} {\ln \left( \frac {n+1 }n \right)}$ and I want to use the squeeze theorem. I do not know how to compare on the right hand side.